# Problema con gráfico de barras con fechas (datetime) en el eje x

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Tengo el siguiente código que me genera un gráfico con eje `x` como fecha y 2 ejes `y`, uno para el `MP-10` y el otro para los equipos el cual lo quiero hacer de barras.

```
date = ["2017-05-20 20:49","2017-05-20 20:50","2017-05-20 20:51","2017-05-20 20:52","2017-05-20 20:53","2017-05-20 20:54","2017-05-20 20:55",
       "2017-05-20 20:56","2017-05-20 20:57","2017-05-20 20:58","2017-05-20 20:59","2017-05-20 21:00","2017-05-20 21:01","2017-05-20 21:02",
       "2017-05-20 21:03","2017-05-20 21:04","2017-05-20 21:05","2017-05-20 21:06","2017-05-20 21:07","2017-05-20 21:08","2017-05-20 21:09",
       "2017-05-20 21:10","2017-05-20 21:11","2017-05-20 21:12","2017-05-20 21:13","2017-05-20 21:14","2017-05-20 21:15","2017-05-20 21:16",
       "2017-05-20 21:17","2017-05-20 21:18","2017-05-20 21:19","2017-05-20 21:20","2017-05-20 21:21","2017-05-20 21:22","2017-05-20 21:23"]
date = pd.to_datetime(date)
mp_10 = [502,507,514,521,528,533,539,544,548,551,553,554,555,555,555,554,553,552,551,551,550,548,547,545,543,541,538,534,530,525,520,515,510,506,501]
equipos = [11,11,11,16,18,19,21,24,24,25,25,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1] #35

df = pd.DataFrame({"fecha": date, "mp-10": mp_10, "totalEquipos": equipos})


## PLOT
sns.set(style='whitegrid', palette="deep", font_scale=1.1, rc={"figure.figsize": [8, 5]})
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
#PLot Line
plot_line = ax.plot(df.fecha, df['mp-10'], color='teal', marker='o')
ax.set_xlim(["2017-05-20 20:46", "2017-05-20 21:25"])
ax.set_xticklabels(df.fecha)
ax.set_ylim([0,700])
ax.set_xlabel("Hora: (20:49 - 21:23)", fontsize= 18)
ax.set_ylabel("MP-10 (ug/m3N)", color="teal", fontsize = 18)
ax.set_title("Peak 3 - MP-10 - Otoño - 20/05/2017", fontsize = 20)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor="teal")
#Plot Bar
ax2 = ax.twinx()
plot_bar= ax2.bar(x = 'fecha', height = 'totalEquipos', data = df, color= 'purple', label='Total equipos', align = 'edge', linewidth= 4)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor= 'purple')
ax2.set_ylabel("Total equipos", color = 'purple', fontsize = 18)
ax2.set_ylim([0,40])
ax2.tick_params(axis='y')
#Legends
lns = plot_line + [plot_bar]
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
ax.legend(lns, labs, loc='center', fontsize=15)
fig.tight_layout()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt);
```

el código me genera el siguiente gráfico de linea y barras:

[image: img del codigo]

Mi problema es que el área marcada con azul está demás y no se como quitarlo.

¿alguien sabe como arreglar esto para que me muestre de forma correcta el gráfico?

Este otro gráfico muestra los puntos correctos que deberían seguir las barras:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El problema se debe al ancho de las barras, dos cosas:

- El ancho de las barras se controla mediante el argumento `width` no `linewith`.
- Las unidades de `width` dependen de las unidades del eje <kbd>x</kbd>, en el caso de fechas son de un día por defecto si no me equivoco. Por lo que `width=1` seria un ancho de 4 dias, un ancho demasiado grande para el rango de fechas que tienes. Un ancho de un minuto sería apropiado. Puedes especificarlo de varias formas:

  - Como un `float`:

    ```
    width=1/1440 # (1 dia = 1440 minutos)
    ```
  - Usando `datetime.timedelta`:

    ```
    import datetime
    width = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
    ```
  - Mediante `pandas.Timedelta`:

    ```
    width = pd.Timedelta(1, "m")
    ```

Otra posibilidad es calcularlo de forma dinámica, lo cual puede ser de ayuda en algunos casos, por ejemplo, calculamos la diferencia entre una fecha y la que le sigue y luego usamos la mínima diferencia encontrada como el ancho para evitar solapamientos:

```
width = df["fecha"].diff().min()
```

Lo que ves aparentemente rellenando el espacio entre barras son en realidad las **barras precedentes que son muy anchas y se solapan con las que les siguen**.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


date = ["2017-05-20 20:49","2017-05-20 20:50","2017-05-20 20:51","2017-05-20 20:52","2017-05-20 20:53","2017-05-20 20:54","2017-05-20 20:55",
       "2017-05-20 20:56","2017-05-20 20:57","2017-05-20 20:58","2017-05-20 20:59","2017-05-20 21:00","2017-05-20 21:01","2017-05-20 21:02",
       "2017-05-20 21:03","2017-05-20 21:04","2017-05-20 21:05","2017-05-20 21:06","2017-05-20 21:07","2017-05-20 21:08","2017-05-20 21:09",
       "2017-05-20 21:10","2017-05-20 21:11","2017-05-20 21:12","2017-05-20 21:13","2017-05-20 21:14","2017-05-20 21:15","2017-05-20 21:16",
       "2017-05-20 21:17","2017-05-20 21:18","2017-05-20 21:19","2017-05-20 21:20","2017-05-20 21:21","2017-05-20 21:22","2017-05-20 21:23"]
date = pd.to_datetime(date)
mp_10 = [502,507,514,521,528,533,539,544,548,551,553,554,555,555,555,554,553,552,551,551,550,548,547,545,543,541,538,534,530,525,520,515,510,506,501]
equipos = [11,11,11,16,18,19,21,24,24,25,25,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1] #35

df = pd.DataFrame({"fecha": date, "mp-10": mp_10, "totalEquipos": equipos})

## PLOT
sns.set(style='whitegrid', palette="deep", font_scale=1.1, rc={"figure.figsize": [8, 5]})
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
#PLot Line
plot_line = ax.plot(df.fecha, df['mp-10'], color='teal', marker='o')
ax.set_xlim(["2017-05-20 20:46", "2017-05-20 21:25"])
ax.set_xticklabels(df.fecha)
ax.set_ylim([0,700])
ax.set_xlabel("Hora: (20:49 - 21:23)", fontsize= 18)
ax.set_ylabel("MP-10 (ug/m3N)", color="teal", fontsize = 18)
ax.set_title("Peak 3 - MP-10 - Otoño - 20/05/2017", fontsize = 20)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor="teal")
#Plot Bar
ax2 = ax.twinx()
width = pd.Timedelta(1, "m")
plot_bar= ax2.bar(x = 'fecha', height = 'totalEquipos', data = df, color= 'purple', label='Total equipos', align="edge", width=width)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor= 'purple')
ax2.set_ylabel("Total equipos", color = 'purple', fontsize = 18)
ax2.set_ylim([0,40])
ax2.tick_params(axis='y')
#Legends
lns = plot_line + [plot_bar]
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
ax.legend(lns, labs, loc='center', fontsize=15)
fig.tight_layout()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt); 


plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ten en cuenta que al usar `aling="edge"` la barra no alinea su centro con su valor en el eje <kbd>x</kbd>, sino que alinea el vértice inferior izquierdo. Por eso en tu código inicial el solapamiento de las barras solo se producía hacia la derecha. Si usas `align="center"` (valor por defecto):

```
plot_bar= ax2.bar(x='fecha',
                  height='totalEquipos',
                  data=df,
                  color= 'purple',
                  label='Total equipos',
                  aling="center"
                  width=width
                  )
```

obtienes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]